# Как взять название модуля из переменной python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как импортировать модуль, если название модуля записано в переменной.
Например:

```
name = "название модуля"
import name

name.somefunc()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше использовать для этого модуль `importlib`

```
import importlib
name = "math"
module = importlib.import_module(name)
print(module.sin(2))
print(module.cos(4))
```

Или можно так

```
name = "math"
module = __import__(name)
print(module.sin(2))
print(module.cos(4))
```

Чтобы можно было импортировать модуль из определённой директории, в [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56606311/7485582) *Gino Mempin* предлагается добавить её в sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/module")
```

Comment: А куда можно записать папку, в которой лежит модуль? Просто у меня модуль лежит в в папке scripts, а импортирую из скрипта main.py

Comment: Обновил ответ..